# python) find all matches using regex (changed to re.findall from re.search)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to extract **all matches** of numbers (nn.nn) next to a keyword (Exhibit). For example,

```
through April 25, 2012

through April 25, 2012 

Exhibit 99.6 

Exhibit 99.10
```

Here is my code.

```
import os,re
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\dul\\Dropbox\\CTO\\test')


def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()

    matchexh = re.findall(r'Exhibit (\d+).(\d+)',text1)
    with open('outfile.txt', "a+") as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n"+matchexh)

files= os.listdir("C:\\Users\\dul\\Dropbox\\CTO\\test")
for file in files:
    if ".txt" in file:
        extract_data(file)
```

When I run this,  I get an error message

> ```
> File "C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\CTO\test\exhibitno.py", line 13, in extract_data  
>    outfile.write("\n"+matchexh)  
> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
> ```

How can I get all matches and list them?

Comment: You're looking for `re.findall()`. `re.search()` stops at the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
matchexh = re.search(r'Exhibit (\d+).(\d+)',text1).group().strip()
```

to:

```
matchexh = re.findall(r'Exhibit (\d+).(\d+)',text1)
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the error **TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects** comes up...

Comment: @Andre Well... `matchexh` is a list, so you'll need to convert it to a string before doing `"\n" + matchexh`. (Maybe use a str.join?)

Comment: add `" ".join(matchexh)` while writing to file.

Comment: Thanks guys! It works!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this as correct answer! Thanks :)